# Reconfigure dangling symlink libc.so.6

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, sudo, symlink

I didn't do the cleverest thing and changed the `/lib64/libc.so.6` symlink - better still it points to something that doesn't exist - and best of all, the path it points to is within `/lib/`, a folder owned by `root`.

How do I (Can I) get `libc.so.6` pointed to the right thing again?

I've seen other threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12249547/4951413) which are able to do it when `libc.so.6` is deleted. I cannot do that as it gives me the output that `/lib64/libc.so.6` cannot be unlinked (presumably because I do not have permissions)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot unlink a symlink then you cannot change it either. Usually only `root` has write (i.e. delete) permission in `/lib` and `/lib64`.

On my system it points to `libc-2.30.so`. In a `root` shell (or with `sudo`) you can do this:

```
cd /lib64
ln -sf libc-2.30.so libc.so.6
```